# Why is capistrano multiconfig not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, rvm-capistrano, multi-configuration

I had a working capistrano setup for my app but I installed the multiconfig gem so that I could deploy to two different servers using capistrano. Running

`cap primary:production deploy`

works perfectly, but when I run `rails s` I get this error:

```
rails s 

/home/sofia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@big/gems/capistrano-multiconfig-3.0.9/lib/capistrano/multiconfig.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Capistrano::DSL (NameError)
    from /home/sofia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@big/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:100:in `require'
    from /home/sofia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@big/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:100:in `rescue in block in require'
    ...
```

This is the directories inside my `config/` folder:

```
deploy
deploy/secondary
deploy/secondary/production.rb.example
deploy/secondary/production.rb
deploy/staging.rb
deploy/primary
deploy/primary/production.rb.example
deploy/primary/production.rb
```

This is my capfile

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
# require 'capistrano/setup'# The README says to remove this line
                            # and leaving it on does not change anything anyway

require 'capistrano/multiconfig'


# Include default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/passenger'
require "whenever/capistrano"


# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

This is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rest-client'

gem 'yui-compressor'
gem 'pg'
gem 'react-rails', '~> 1.5.0'

gem "paperclip", "~> 4.3"

gem 'aws-sdk-rails'

gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem 'tod'

...

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger', '>= 0.1.1'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  # Allows us to specify a separate configuration for each application/service
  gem "capistrano-multiconfig"


  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'railroady'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug with capistrano-multiconfig v3.0.9, now fixed in v3.0.10